# Words for different levels of crying

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

[Another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/123112/101928) asks for the written sounds of different levels of crying (wah-wah, boo-hoo), but I was wondering if there are names for different levels of crying.

For instance, is there any way to refer to mild crying besides "mild crying'?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: There’s tearing up, sniffling, crying, sobbing, wailing,  shrieking

Comment: @curiousdannii Searching English.se

Comment: And apparently testosterone-reducing crying: "The new study places human tears in a family of fluids that includes urine and anogenital gland secretions"  http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2011/01/06/AR2011010603490.html

Comment: @curiousdannii were you the downvote?

Comment: @TimRomano lol "Anogenital gland secretions"... yuck!  Tear drops are nicer :o)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every human has his own ways of expressing pain. Levels of crying vary with sex and age. A man's cry is different from a woman's. Similarly, a toddler's cry differs from an adolescent's. More importantly, however, there are no current studies or research about the different levels of crying. Nevertheless, a blogger made an illustration titled [*Types of Crying*](http://berkaanonymous.blogspot.com/2011/06/types-of-crying.html) where two factors are considered: **Pathetic-ness and Sympathy Elicited**.

> **Whimpering**: Soft crying usually including few or no tears at all; Often incorporates muttering and/or high-pitched sighs.
>
> **Silent Tears**: Soft, inaudible crying that does not draw attention; May manifest only in a single tear rolling down one’s cheek.
>
> **Sniveling**: Audible, but soft crying, also prone to muttering and erratic breathing; May also show signs of drool or mucus.
>
> **Weeping**: A gentler version of sobbing; Involves soft, steady stream of tears with some times lightly audible signs of distress.
>
> **Sobbing**: Heavy crying with a large volume tears flowing steadily; Generally audible but not inappropriately loud.
>
> **Hyperventilate-Crying**: Forceful crying causing heavy breathing, resulting in the inability to speak or produce sounds even resembling
>   words.
>
> **Blubbering**: Unattractive, loud crying. Characterized by mutters, truncated, erratic breathing, clinched facial expressions and hunched
>   posture.
>
> **Scream-Crying**: Violent crying accompanied with bouts of yelling or sometimes shrieking. May also include slapping, punching or other
>   physical expressions of distress.

There is a certain theory about 5 stages of grief formulated by [Kubler-Ross-- the Bereavement Theory](http://www.recover-from-grief.com/kubler-ross-stages-of-grief.html) as well. It may not answer your question but it entails that every human being has the same bereavement process.

Comment: No problem! Loved the content of your answer :)

Comment: @Aishwarya A R why did you change _their_ to _his_ in the first sentence (**Every human has his own ways of expressing pain**). Do you think that only males are  human beings? O_O

Comment: Thank you both. That was a very good answer?

Comment: http://www.psychologicalscience.org/index.php/news/releases/cry-me-a-river-the-psychology-of-crying.html

Comment: @Amande: The original statement was like so: _Every human have their own ways of expressing pain_. After changing _have_ to _has_, I couldn't leave the plural noun _their_ to solve the gender neutrality issue. I really forgot to consider feminist views while editing the answer. My apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget bawling and crocodile tears.
Also some of these forms of crying, like sobbing, can cause full body movement, such as making your shoulders to shake.